# "my" vs "local" and the use of braces

Tags: perl, scope

record.txt

```
name: shimmer
addr: 192.168.1.11
owner: David Davis
building: main
-=-
name: bendir
addr: 192.168.1.3
owner: cindy Coltrane
building: west
-=-
name: sulawesi
addr: 192.168.1.12
owner: Ellen Monk
building: main
-=-
name: sander
addr: 192.168.1.55
owner: Alex rollins
building: east
```

database.pl

```
my $datafile = 'record.txt';
my $recordsep = "-=-\n";


open my $DATAFILE, '<', "$datafile" or die "unable to open datafile:$!\n";

{
    local $/= $recordsep;       #prepare to read in database file one record at a time
    print "#\n# host file = GENERATED BY $o\n$ DO NOT EDIT BY HAND!\n#\n";


    my %record;
    while(<$DATAFILE>) {
        chomp;      #remove the record separator

        #split into key1,value1, ....bingo, hash of record
        %record = split /:\s*|\n/;
        print "$record{addr}\t$record{name} $record{building} \n";
    }
    close $DATAFILE;
}
```

I have a few questions about this perl code.

1. What's the point of having the code in braces `{ }` after the `open` line?
2. What's the point of doing `local $/= $recordsep;`? `local` vs `my`?
3. What's the meaning of `$o\n$` in the line

   ```
   print "#\n# host file = GENERATED BY $o\n$ DO NOT EDIT BY HAND!\n#\n";
   ```

Comment: Note: Makes no sense to put the `local` in the curlies and not the `open`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The braces define the scope where the `local` value of `$/` is in effect. Outside the braces the variable holds its original value. Without them `$/` would retain the new value up to the end of the file.
2. You can't use `my` on `$/` because it is a *global* value. `my` declares a lexical value that is only in existence for the enclosing block. `local` is used to assign a temporary (local) value to a global value that is still accessible everywhere.
3. The effect those are having is to interpolate the values of variables `$o` and `$DO` into the string at that point. It looks like a mistake: `DO` is obviously part of the text. It's most likely that `$o` is the name of the **o**riginator, `\n` is an embedded newline and the second `$` is spurious.

   I imagine there is no `use strict` or `use warnings` in place on this code, and the output looks like this. No one has noticed the missing `DO`!

```
# host file = GENERATED BY originator
 NOT EDIT BY HAND!
#
```

Comment: In fact, `$ DO` is most likely a typo for `# DO`.

Answer (score 5):

The `my` declares a *lexical* variable (also known as local variable outside of Perl).

You can declare global variables with `our`.

The `local` does not declare a variable, but rather backs up a global variable. That is

```
our $var = 1;

{
   local $var = 42;
   say $var;
}

say $var;
```

outputs

```
42
1
```

On leaving the block, the old value of `$var` is reinstated. This does not work with lexical  (`my`) variables, you can just declare another lexical variable of the same name instead.

The punctuation variables are all globals. The `$/` for example is the *input record separator*, as documented in `perlvar`. A readline operation will read until an EOF, or until after the `$/` value was read. Also, `chomp` will remove this string from the end of the line.

It is considered good style to modify these special variables only in a tightly defined scope, hence the block.